# How to call ng-click function variable in controller on Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Here i need to call angularjs ng-click function variable in controller

**Controller.js**

```
$scope.basicDetail = function(){
        var age = $scope.healthplan.insurer.age;
        console.log(age);
    };

// console.log(age);
```

How can i call ng-click function variable in controller

**Updated**

**view.ejs**

```
<select name="insurer_age" ng-model="healthplan.insurer.age" ng-init="(_Array = []).length = 83;" id="input" class="form-control">
                <option value=""> select your age</option>
                <option ng-repeat="i in _Array track by $index" value="{{$index+18}}">{{$index+18}} years</option>
            </select>
<input type="button" ng-click="basicDetail()" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
```

Comment: what you need exactly??can you add more clarity on your question please.

Comment: You can directly call it like $scope.functionName().. 
And please provide the view where ng-click is used

Comment: Have you tried to call the function as `$scope.basicDetail();` ?

Comment: see above i have updated my question @Dreamweaver

Comment: you should be able to do it using $scope.basicDetail(), Only if controllerAs has been used, this may not work,

Comment: you need the selected value to be accessed in controller???

Comment: Are you facing a problem in the code you've provided? I don't see any errors that I could point out.

Comment: Also, have you defined age as `$scope.healthplan.insurer.age = 18;` or something similar? Otherwise `ng-model` won't find anything to bind to. Other than that, your code is correct. Only thing I can say is use an alias: `controllerAs`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.basicDetail()
```

It is obvious

Answer (score 0):

Just be carefull,because you create your function as a variable , you should first create it and then call it ,just like that :

```
//1.create 
$scope.basicDetail = function(){
        var age = $scope.healthplan.insurer.age;
        console.log(age);
    };

//2.call
$scope.basicDetail();
```

I dont see any other problem with that.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <input type="button" ng-click="basicDetail()" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
```

This is the right way to call a controller function using ng-click.

Comment: it is copied from the question and he actually wants to know that how he can call the function from the controller itself.

Comment: ok its my mistake then you can call function like : 
$scope.YourControllerFunctionName.
in this you need to call $scope.basicDetail();

Comment: @moks Not really, it'd be something like `$scope.myFunction()`, and the `()` is mandatory.